# Store graph in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, directed-graph

What is the most efficient way to store a directed graph with vertices and edges in `mongodb`?

I have stored it as a collection `node` and a collection `edge` where each edge has `source` and `target` both pointing at the `node` collection.

But is this the most efficient way to do it if I want to traverse the graph and retrieve successors and predecessors?

## Edit

Each node and edge won't have much other data (maybe 2 other fields) and each node will not have many edges (between 1-5).

Comment: Is there a lot of other data in the nodes?  Do nodes have lots of edges per node?  Will you need to traverse the graph deeply without looking at other data?  It's impossible to answer this without knowing what the data and access patterns look like.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb is not suitable for graphs. There are better alternatives than mongoDB as graph database. You can explore Orientdb, it's open sourced. If you are looking for more professional and performance optimized graph database, then go for Neo4j.